# iOS12 is causing an error on Metal Command Buffer execution, render is glitchy or doesn't occur

Tags: ios, swift, gpu, scenekit, metal

We have an app that uses `Metal` to render. This app works correctly on devices running iOS11. When using the same app on devices running iOS12, we started getting glitches and sometimes hangs in the rendering. We also tried recompiling for iOS12 and are getting the same bad behavior. On the console we are getting the following different messages:

> 2018-09-22 09:22:29.508576-0500 OurApp [1286:84481] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)
>
> 2018-09-22 09:29:55.654426-0500 OurApp [1286:84625] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
>
> 2018-09-22 09:34:37.718054-0500 OurApp [1286:87354] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)

With the first two messages the rendering seems glitchy, where a blank screen is presented and then finally the rendering occurs on screen. With the last message the rendering doesn't actually occur and the message continues being displayed until we move to a different view.

This app uses `SceneKit`, instantiates a `SCNView` and uses a default `CIContext`. It also uses the Physically Based Lighting model, which forces the `Metal` renderer to be used. The app has a simple `SCNNode` geometry, a cylinder. Each geometry object of the cylinder gets a normal texture (3 in total).  The same diffuse, metalness and roughness values are applied to all the geometry objects of the cylinder.

Has anybody ran into this problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Thanks

UPDATE: The problem seems to be caused when an image is used as the scene's lighting environment:

```
let scene = SCNScene()
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = UIImage(named: "ourLightingEnvironmentImage")
```

When a lighting environment isn't used, the problem goes away. This is starting to look like an Apple bug, we will file one. We are stuck because we need the lighting environment to produce realistic reflections for the models in our app.

Comment: I had the same issue, on some but not all iOS 12 devices, when loading a simple scene created in the SceneKit editor. Thanks to your update, the issue went away when I changed the lightning environment away from the default "Procedural Sky". In contrast to your observation, it did not hang when using one of my own images as the lightning environment. Please do file a bug, and report here when Apple has fixed it.

Comment: It seems like this is only a problem on the iPhone 6. We have filed the bug with Apple. The problem with Apple's bug reporting mechanism is that the priority of a bug is determined by the number of duplicates they get and second you never get any updates or feedback on the status of a bug.

Comment: For me it looks like Apple has completely broken the lightning with iOS 12. I see multiple issues, also with fog, the view distance, black areas during walking through my maze ... . I've also checken on multiple devices: All devices with iOS 11.4.3 are working fine, all devices with iOS 12 show artefacts :-(

Comment: Same issue here running our SceneKit app with Physically Based lighting and materials on iOS 12.0.1 with both iPhone 6 and iPad Mini. No issues with iOS 11.4.

Comment: @LenK please log a bug report with Apple. It seems like they only pay attention to bugs which have duplicates. Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue with iPhone XS, XS Max and XR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632453/why-iphones-xr-xs-and-xs-max-doesnt-apply-environment-image-to-scene-in-arkit But in my case, is mandatory to use a environment image... We should log a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, caused by high resolution environment lightning images.

The solution is to resize these images, 1000x500 is what we are using now. Works perfectly.

Comment: I had the problem as well and still in iOS 12.4 - after checking the default environment map that files with Apples ARKit Template (I have the issue in ARKit) I remarked , that the resolution of the map is way too high. Like more than 4000 by 2000 pixels. I reduced the resolution to 1024x512 and the error went away immediatly. (I also observed, the more complex the entire scene setup becomes, the more this error was throwing)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issues for the moment by choosing OpenGL ES as render mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, using OpenGL over Metal solves the errors problem. The problem is that our app needs the Physically Based Lighting model with environment lighting and this is only available in Metal.

Answer (score 1):

I just received an update to the bug I had filed with Apple:

> Apple Developer Relations
>
> We believe this issue is resolved in the latest iOS 12.2 beta.  Please test with the latest iOS beta. If you still have issues, please update your bug report with any relevant logs or information that could help us investigate.  iOS beta https://developer.apple.com/download/"

Comment: Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)
[Assert] Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C15.1:2][0x10b30da00] get output frames failed, state 8196
TIC Read Status [15:0x0]: 1:57

Comment: Occuring same issue with IOS 12.3.1 with in iPhone X as well.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be having the exact same problem. Also using ARKit and the default sceneKit Editor, I kept getting the IOAF code 4 error infinitely when the screen freezes up.

I fixed my problem by changing the environment from "Procedural Sky" to "None". Doesn't lag or freeze anymore, but this is hardly the solution as my AR object now has no lighting or environment. I believe there is a fix coming in iOS 12.2 Beta, but have yet to update.

Hope my solution helps others.